# Será um erro na Unity ou não interfere no programa?

Tags: unity3d, quebras-de-linha

Apareceu este erro na `Unity` gostaria de saber o que é erro e como resolvelo

> There are inconsistent line endings in the 'Assets/Scripts/teste.cs'
>   script. Some are Mac OS X (UNIX) and some are Windows. This might lead
>   to incorrect line numbers in stacktraces and compiler errors. Many
>   text editors can fix this using Convert Line Endings menu commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como a própria mensagem indica, o seu arquivo `teste.cs` (que é um arquivo texto, contendo linhas de código) tem terminações de linha inconsistentes. Acontece que no Windows a terminação de uma linha em um arquivo texto é indicada por dois caracteres (CR + LF, que são os caracteres de *[carriage return](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return)* e de *[line feed](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_Feed)*). No Unix apenas o LF é utilizado, e no MAC apenas o CR é utilizado.

A mensagem também dá uma dica sobre o que pode acontecer devido a essa inconsistência. A Unity pode exibir números de linha incorretos em mensagens de log e/ou em mensagens de erro de compilação. Não são problemas muito graves. Mas como podem atrapalhar a sua depuração de outros problemas, faz sentido corrigí-los.

A própria mensagem também indica como resolvê-los usando um editor de texto. O [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (totalmente gratuito), por exemplo, tem uma opção para ajudar com isso. Abra o arquivo no Notepad++, vá no menu "Editar" (ou *Edit*, em inglês) e escolha "Conversão final de linha" (ou *EOL Conversion*, em inglês) e selecione o sistema operacional utilizado (Windows ou MAC, por exemplo). Então salve o arquivo e reabra-o normalmente na Unity.